# Command Line arguments handling on Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, command-line-arguments

I normally use 'getopt' for command line argument handling in Linux but sadly i come to know just now that it does not work in Visual Studio. Since this is my first time coding visual C++ 2010 code so i am having trouble parsing command line arguments. Pls see code below:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string cfgFilePath = "";
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout<<"Usage: ApplicationName ConfigFile\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    //cfgFilePath = argv[1];    //<<--- Ideally i want to do this. But it doesnt work

    printf("\nEntered String: %s.", argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

When i run its exe like "**app.exe abcd**" then the output i get is "**Entered String: a**.". Why is this happening and what i can do to correct things.

Also what can i do to make commented out line to work. Here i am getting error

> "*error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type '_TCHAR *' (or there is no acceptable conversion*)"

Thanks

Comment: "Entered String: a": Are you sure that you call the program with "app.exe abcd"? At least, i can say that even in VS and Windows, the described behaviour is not intended. There have to be  error somewhere here.

Comment: Yes. I do call as app.exe abcd. I followed sample s in msdn and was hoping to get a complete string. Don't know why is this the case.

Comment: Is this compiled for Unicode?

Comment: @HokageSama _TCHAR is a macro that is controlled by the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` macros, you need to use an `std::wstring`

Comment: @Mgetz it gives an error stating "error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [1]' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'"

Comment: @OldProgrammer I suppose Unicode would be enabled in my visual studio. I will search options to turn it off and give it a try.

Comment: Well, turning off Unicode from project properties made commented part work. Also in this case i was able to get complete string. Thanks..